# Laptop sudden error message: “battery is not genuine”

Tags: laptop, battery, lenovo-laptop

Good day.

A laptop computer, Lenovo Thinkpad E450.

This morning when the power turn on it pops up an error message:

```
"This system may not support batteries that are not genuine Lenovo-made or authorized. 
The system will continue to boot, but may not charge unauthorized batteries,"
```

The machine usually works fine and I didn't have any hardware changes in the past few days.
No idea how this is happening.

I tried to search solutions on Internet, both https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-11e-Windows-13-E-and/E545-no-longer-thinks-its-battery-is-a-lenovo-authorized-battery/m-p/2147643 and https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-3000-and-Essential/G700-Energy-Management-says-battery-is-not-genuine-and-won-t/td-p/1281261 suggest to remove the battery before set up.

The battery of the laptop is hidden down the keyboard that is very complicated to remove.

Is there any way to fix this problem without remove the battery?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try following the steps in the link without removing the battery?